# C++ - friend functions

Tags: c++, friend

I am trying to make a simple friend function work, but not in just one source file. I seem to get an error and I can't seem to find an answer why.

Please have a look at my code:

```
----------classOne.h--------------
#ifndef CLASSONE_H_
#define CLASSONE_H_

using namespace std;

class ClassOne {
private:
    int m_a;
    int  m_b;
public:
    ClassOne(int a, int b);
    void printValuesOne();
    friend void ClassTwo::twoPrintsOne();
};
```

-

```
----------classOne.cpp------------
#include <iostream> 
#include "classOne.h"

using namespace std;

ClassOne::ClassOne(int a, int b) {
    m_a = a;
    m_b = b;
}

void ClassOne::printValuesOne() {
    cout << "m_a: " << m_a << " " << "m_b: " << m_b << endl;
}
```

.

```
----------classTwo.h-------------
#ifndef CLASSTWO_H_
#define CLASSTWO_H_

using namespace std;

class ClassTwo {
private:
    int m_c;
    int m_d;
public:
    ClassTwo(int c, int d);
    void printValuesTwo();
    twoPrintsOne();
};

#endif
```

-

```
---------classTwo.cpp-----------
#include <iostream> 
#include "classTwo.h"

using namespace std;

ClassTwo::ClassTwo(int c, int d) {
    m_c = c;
    `enter code here`m_d = d;
}

void ClassTwo::printValuesTwo() {
    cout << "m_c: " << m_c << " " << "m_d: " << m_d << endl;
}

void twoPrintsOne() {
    cout << "ClassTwo: " << m_a: " << m_a << " " << "m_b: " << m_b << endl;
}
```

Basically ClassOne and ClassTwo are the same sort of thing, but only one of ClassTwo's method has access to all of ClassOne's members, so ClassTwo can print ClassOne's member variables. However, when I try to compile the whole program (I haven't provided the main method here), I get this error an error:

```
classOne.h:19:15: error: ‘ClassTwo’ has not been declared
friend void ClassTwo::twoPrintsOne();
            ^
```

Can someone help and explain?

Answer (score 0):

`ClassOne` doesn't know about `ClassTwo`, therefore it cannot befriend with any of its methods. You have to add:

```
#include "classTwo.h"
```

on top of your classOne.h.

Comment: That fixes the problem, but then it brings another problem to the twoPrintsOne() function in classTwo.cpp, that m_a and m_b are not declared in the scope. I'm not sure what they mean and how I can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused with what "friend" is supposed to do.
"friending" ClassTwo will allow ClassTwo to access the private members of ClassOne as if they were public.
It will not link those members between the two classes in any way.

You could have ClassTwo inherit from ClassOne, or add a ClassOne member in ClassTwo